# Android gradle fails to resolve jitpack snapshot build dependency

Tags: android, build.gradle, jitpack

I had a GitHub project forked and some fixes applied to it. Now would like to use it as dependency in a project of mine. Have followed the instructions provided at [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/docs/) but gradle build fails to find it.

build.gradle (all projects)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

build.gradle (module)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.user:repo:e91058a'
}
```

Have tried calling `File->Sync` in Android Studio and running `gradlew build --refresh-dependencies`. Also tried defining `dev-SNAPSHOT` as the version number instead of commit hash. But it always ends up with `Failed to resolve` error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your repositority on jitpack.io, and verify that the snapshot was actually built. (Enter your repo url, select 'branches', you must see a green icon near your commit sha)
Also if your repository is private, you'd need to add access token in build.gradle (you can find it in ur account setting)